# Refactor observable to call a NgbModal in a service

Tags: angular, typescript, ng-bootstrap

I have a service in angular 11 that use to call a Ngbmodal component to subscribe when i closed that component. This is the code:

```
  showMessage(messageData: MessageDataDTO): Observable<MessageResult> {
    return new Observable((result) => {
      const dialogRef = this.dialog.open(
        MessageComponent,
        this.ngbModalOptions
      );
      dialogRef.componentInstance.data = messageData;
      dialogRef.closed.subscribe((res) => {
        result.next(res);
        result.complete();
      });
    });
  }
```

How could I refactor the code for omit the `result.next(res); result.complete();`?

Comment: why the outer Observable if dialogRef.close already is an observable? Just get rid of the wrapper and return that.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

@Clashsoft upss you're right. I refactored the code to this:

```
showMessage(messageData: MessageDataDTO): Observable<MessageResult> {
  const dialogRef = this.dialog.open(MessageComponent, this.ngbModalOptions);
  dialogRef.componentInstance.data = messageData;
  return dialogRef.closed;
}
```

Solved.